# ValueError: Shapes (None, 2, 28) and (None, 2) are incompatible // How can i transform 2 onehotvectors to one

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, multilabel-classification

I'm working on a classification Problem. The data i use is from the Aras Dataset. One line of the Data looks like the following:

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 12 17
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 12 17
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 12 17

From the first 19 columns represent sensordata(binary). The last two columns represent the activites of two persons who lived in a household, where the data was collected.

i have diveded the dataset into different pieces, because it's not small at all, 30 Days with one datapoint every second.

What i want to do with my model: I want to train my model so it can predict what Person A&B are doing at the moment.

So here is my Code(X-Data:Column 1-19;Y-Data_Column 20-21):

```
*import keras
from keras import losses
from keras import regularizers
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
import numpy as np
from keras.utils import to_categorical
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
batch_size =512
no_epochs = 5
verbosity = 1
x_train=np.loadtxt('x_train.txt')
x_val=np.loadtxt('x_val.txt')
x_test=np.loadtxt('x_test.txt')
y_train=np.loadtxt('y_train.txt')
y_val=np.loadtxt('y_val.txt')
y_test=np.loadtxt('y_test.txt')
y_train_onehot=keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train)
y_val_onehot=keras.utils.to_categorical(y_val)
y_test_onehot=keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test)
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=[19,]))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(
    learning_rate=0.000001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-07, amsgrad=False,
    name='Adam'),
    metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
history=model.fit(x_train, y_train_onehot, batch_size, epochs=no_epochs,verbose=verbosity, shuffle=True,validation_data=(x_val, y_val_onehot))
```

---

Error: ValueError: Shapes (None, 2, 28) and (None, 2) are incompatible

---

When i do not convert the labels to the onehot format it is working, but it is not a useful result (i guess). Problem is, that i got this valueerror at the end and i know it has something to do with the fact that inside the vector are two onehot-vectors, but i have no idea how to solve this issue.

--> i tried to put both onehot vectors into one, but then every line has 729 columns(27*27 for each labelcombination), but then the labeldata gots to big an python won't work the script out.

Windows 10
Keras 2.4.3
Tensorflow 2.3.1
Python 3.7.9

I'm new to this whole topic, so don't be mad with me, if my question is stupid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model requires two outputs. It is impossible with Sequential API. Create a new model with Functional API

Comment: I can't help but notice that some of your answers are better suited for the comments section. This doesn't really qualify as a solution to the problem.

Comment: @Nicolas Gervais Thank you for comment. I think that if the answer is accepted - it is a solution. If additional explanation needed - then I will provide it. It is better to have short answer than have no answer at all. I imagine if it was my question and I've got this answer - I would be happy. But you are right - for some people it could be too short

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. I'm not fully aware of the community guidlines yet, but for me this answer works. It gives me a direction and an idea of what to do next.

Comment: @FelixHahn Please don't forget to accept the answer when you check that it is correct